# Sketch a proof that stCONN is in the class NSPACE(log n) = NL .

Tags: computational-complexity

Given a graph G as input stCONN is the problem of determining if there is a path from start vertex s to target vertex t. Sketch a proof that stCONN is in the class NSPACE(log n) = NL.

Can somebody please explain this to me as simply as possible?
I don't know if I understand the problem correctly, wouldn't Savitch's theorem be enough to prove this?

Comment: Saavitch’s theorem shows that any problem that’s already in NSPACE($\log n$) also belongs to DSPACE($\log^2 n$).  It does not help you to show that a specific problem belongs to NSPACE.

Comment: can you please briefly and simply explain this proof

Comment: What don’t you understand about https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/St-connectivity ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be our input graph, and let $s, t \in V(G)$ be our vertices. We may guess an $s \to t$ path, one vertex at a time.

Precisely, we do the following:

- Let $\textsf{current} := s$.
- While $\textsf{current} \neq t$:

  - Guess a vertex $v$ and check that $(\textsf{current}, v) \in E(G)$. If so, set $\text{current} := v$.

We are only storing two vertices at any point in time. Each vertex requires $\lceil \log(|V|) \rceil$ bits to specify, so we are using $O(\log(n))$ space.

Comment: We need to store additionally $\lceil \log(|V|) \rceil$ bits to store the number of steps we have made. Otherwise we can potentially get stuck in a loop.